# Send Email To DataExtension from FuelSDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

I am able to send email to data extension using SendEmailToDataExtension function of php FuelSDK.

What I am looking to send email to data extension (imported from salesforce) but data extension should be filtered. I have field (category) in my data extension  which I can use to segregate subscribers/records.

e:g my DataExtension have 20,000 records and have 4 categories, each category have 5000 records. Now if I need to send email to category 1 which should send email to 5000 not to 20,000 records.

Earlier I saw some where you can set a filter but cannot find in FuelSDK.

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 1):

FuelSDK for PHP does not have built-in support for the FilterDefinition object which would be required if you wanted to send to a filtered version of a data extension.  This object is available by accessing the SOAP API directly.